# Create a Plone private site

Tags: plone

I should create a private plone site.
I tried to read both the howto on plone.org
http://plone.org/documentation/kb/creating-private-plone-site
both of the responses already made an identical request for this channel
[What is the best way to create a Plone private site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370884/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-plone-private-site)
but I have not found a solution.

I do not want to use (if possible) as a product http://pypi.python.org/pypi/iw.rejectanonymous but I'd only change the workflow or permissions.

I thought "enough" to set as the default workflow "intranet_workflow" where state internally_published permits "View" and "Access contents information" only to authenticated but, so 'doing, connect to my site only see a blank page (I tried it on a basic install version 4.1.2) and the user isn't redirect to the login form.

Thanks for any help
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it "just works"(TM) like this:

- create a new plone site
- go to /@@types-controlpane and set the intrantet workflow as default workflow
- and do not forget to apply changes.

after that, visiting the portal will redirect unauthenticated users to the login_form
(i tested it with a plain plone4.1.3 site)

no idea why you just see a blank page. any add-ons or themes installed?

Comment: Well, i try it on Ploud.com with a clean site.
I will try it with a clean unified install on a machine ... perhaps there is a problem on Ploud
Thanks

Comment: With a local fresh Plone 4.1.3 installation, it's works.
Thank you ... probably there is a problem on Ploud.com

Answer (score 1):

For Plone 5 I followd fRiSi answer but I haven't found /@@types-controlpane, however there's a way to get to that menu through ZMI.

Go to `/<plone_site>/portal_workflow` then under **Workflows by type** in **(Default)** field replace simple_publication_workflow with `intranet_folder_worflow`.

The list of available workflows can be found under `/<plone_site>/portal_workflow/manage_main`

Then click on **Change** and **Update Security Settings**. This should update workflow for all objects on the Plone site.

[image]